# Can my girlfriend cross the US / Mexican border if her child is a US citizen, during COVID

Tags: mexico

My girlfriend's child was born in the US, but my girlfriend is not a US citizen. The child is a minor. She does not have a current passport, but she does have a visa which allows her to cross normally. Since her child is a US citizen, is she allowed to cross the land border from Mexico to the US, even with COVID restrictions?

Comment: Is her visa a border crossing card?  Is her son's school in the area within which she is permitted to travel after entering with a border crossing card and no passport?

Answer (score 1):

No. Under INA 212(a)(7)(B), a nonimmigrant is inadmissible to the US unless they have a passport that is valid until 6 months after the end of the period of admission (or, for passports of countries in the [6-month club](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2), valid until the end of the period of admission). See [9 FAM 302.1-4](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM030201.html#M302_1_4).

If her passport is already expired, she cannot use it to enter.

Comment: Once her passport is renewed, can she cross by land even with COVID restrictions?

Comment: @ThrowawayDude: What is the purpose of her visit to the US?

Comment: For enrolling her son (who is a US citizen) in school

Comment: @ThrowawayDude: Then no, land entry to the US is still restricted to essential travel. She would have to fly in.

Comment: This answer overlooks the (likely?) possibility that the girlfriend has a border crossing card, which may be used without a passport, though with significant restrictions, and which functions as a B visa when presented in combination with a passport.